When shouldn't I use possessive s?
What should I say? The "island beaches are clean" or "the island's beaches are clean"?
And when shouldn't I use possessives?
Thanks in advance.

This question is similar to: City center or city's center?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. See also Using the Saxon genitive or not? and Possessive "‘s" or "of", or neither?, among others

When shouldn't I use possesssive s?

The only "truth" here is you shouldn't use possessive s in contexts where native speakers don't use it. Don't forget that native speakers aren't explicitly taught whether and when to refer to the car's door rather than the car door or the door of the car. And all those forms do in fact occur, so there's definitely no clear-cut "rule" here. Just read / listen to more English text.

...but I suggest you start with the assumption that you can use a noun adjectivally to modify another noun (as a "noun adjunct"). You'll have far less to learn if you concentrate on getting a feel for contexts where native speakers don't use noun adjuncts, rather than trying to learn when you should avoid using the Saxon genitive 's

Stop answering in comments and wrecking people's answers. I doubt most learners  understand the term noun adjunct.

I doubt it too. That's why I pointed out that you can use a noun adjectivally to modify another noun. I'm not "answering" in that comment - it's a "frame challenge", which has precisely zero implications for any answers that may be posted. Which they shouldn't be anyway, since the question has been asked and answered before.

I. "The island beaches" may refer to "specific island beaches" or "island beaches in general":
OP has asked which is correct:


"The island beaches are clean" or
"The island's beaches are clean"?


In English, the way we generalize categories depends on the type of noun:
For animals or species, we typically use the  singular form with the definite article to generalize.
Example:

"The kangaroo is a native of Australia."
"The wolf hunts  in packs."

For physical objects, places, or groups, we often use the plural form with the definite article to generalize.
Examples:

"The island beaches are clean."
"The sandy deserts cover large areas of the Earth."
"The ancient ruins attract tourists."

In this case:
"The island beaches are clean" could refer to either specific beaches on an island or all island beaches in general, depending on the context.
Similar examples:

"The fresh water springs are vital for the ecosystem." (All springs.)
"The coastal towns are vulnerable to flooding." (All towns on coasts.)

II. "The island's beaches" refers to a single island's beaches only.

Using "'s" (possessive form) implies ownership or belonging to a specific entity.
Therefore, "The island's beaches are clean" refers only to the beaches of a single, particular island.

This distinction is important when you want to specify that the beaches belong to one island rather than referring to beaches on islands in general.
Examples of possessives:

"The city's streets" = Streets belonging to one city.
"The river's banks" = Banks of one specific river.

III. When should you avoid possessive forms?
In English, we often prefer compound nouns over possessive forms, especially for general references:

"School bus" is more natural than "the school's bus."
"Ocean waves" is more natural than "the ocean's waves."
"Island beaches" is more natural than "the island's beaches" when you are speaking about a general category.

Here is a website which would be helpful:
Compound nouns and possessive forms..

.
However, we often prefer one form over the other because it’s more common: bus stop, car key, toothpaste, car park, ice cream, haircut, etc..
.
We can use a compound noun to refer to a container, which is usually empty: a tea cup, a wine glass, a beer glass, a matchbox, etc..
Can you pass me those tea cups? I’m going to wash them. (=they are empty).
She keeps the insects that she catches in that matchbox..
.
But note that we use noun + of + noun to refer to a container together with its contents: a cup of tea, a glass of wine, a glass of beer, a box of matches, etc..


Please do not post charts like that. Low vision people can't see them.

Thanks James. Your answer is so clear and helpful

@OA I believe normally a learner is looking for answers in detail. I add links in my answer which would be helpful to the learners.

Island beaches (without any determiners) would be understood to refer to a category or class of beaches: those on islands. Thus here island is used adjectivally. One might do so in utterances like Island beaches tend to be home to a larger proportion of unique indigenous species than are continental beaches.
When referring to those beaches on a particular island or group of islands, one could say things like the island’s beaches or the beaches on these islands or an island’s beaches.

When shouldn't I use possessive s?

@OA He has answered that. You don't use the possessive when  you use the word island as an adjective.

IOW it depends on the context.

Yes, I mean when can't I use possessive s generally? In orher words, are there any cases where using pissessive s is forbidden?

It is never forbidden, you can always use it. Inanimate objects tend to be used as attributive nouns ("the car door") but it is still possible to use the possessive ("the car's door")
